# Is there such thing as a VLOOKUP that recognises repeated numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, offset, vlookup

I have a list of values in column A on an excel TAB and on the column B next to it I have a list of words. On another TAB, I'm trying to retrieve the words from B where A has the smallest value, then the 2nd smaller value, 3rd, etc.

Example: Column A would have (2,3,3,6,8) and B (car,dog,cat,house,boat)

I firstly created a column where I retrieved the smallest values:

- On column **X1** I added: `SMALL('Table'!$A:$A,1)`
- On column **X2** I added: `SMALL('Table'!$A:$A,2)`
- etc...

and then a VLOOKUP worked for me:

- On column **Y1** I added: `VLOOKUP(X1,'Table'!$A:$B,2,FALSE)`
- On column **Y2** I added: `VLOOKUP(X2,'Table'!$A:$B,2,FALSE)`

So far so good. My issue is when my values repeat. *i.e.: 
In the example above, whenever the function finds the value 3 in column A, I get the word *dog* twice instead of *dog* and *cat* because it just displays the first value the vlookup finds.

I've tried adding an offset: `=OFFSET(SMALL('Table'!$A:$A,1),1,0)` but not sure if it works to fetch from other TABS.

Any help or workaround for this please? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using Index/match instead of VLOOKUP and adding one to the match position if the same value has occurred once before, two if it has occurred twice before etc.:-

```
=INDEX(Table!B:B,MATCH(A2,Table!A:A,0)+COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A2))
```

You can also use something like this to get the smallest, second smallest etc. rather than hard-coding it:-

```
=SMALL(Table!$A:$A,ROW(1:1))
```

[image]

OK the trick I'm going to use to separate rows with equal values is to add a small amount to each row to make the value unique. Here are my formulae:-

```
=LARGE(IF(A$2:A$9="Restaurants",C$2:C$9),ROW(1:1))
```

to get the largest value, this is a standard formula

```
=INDEX(D$2:D$9,MATCH(LARGE(IF(A$2:A$9="Restaurants",C$2:C$9+ROW(C$2:C$9)/10^7),ROW(1:1)),C$2:C$9+ROW(C$2:C$9)/10^7,0))
```

to get the matching city. This will work even if the equal values aren't in adjacent rows.

I don't know how many rows you have in your actual data, if it was more than 100 you'd need to use a smaller amount than .01.

Pleae note that these are Array Formulae and need to be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

For the smallest ones, just change LARGE to SMALL.

[image]

If you wanted to exclude any non-numeric values like "not ranked" you would need

```
=INDEX(D$2:D$9,MATCH(LARGE(IF((A$2:A$9="Restaurants")*ISNUMBER(C$2:C$9),C$2:C$9+ROW(C$2:C$9)/10^7),ROW(1:1)),C$2:C$9+ROW(C$2:C$9)/10^7,0))
```

I wouldn't recommend changing it to use D:D, C:C etc. because it would be slow, but it would work.

Comment: Thanks for this Tom.

Comment: I'm still around with my issue and can't seem to find a proper solution or I'm probably not excel savvy enough to see the answer.

Comment: OK I will add to my answer

Comment: Tom, I always just use `+ROW(C$2:C$9)/10^7` to add increment for the tie-break

Comment: Yes that's safer than .01 - will add it to my answer.

Comment: Tom, many many thanks - this worked like a charm. Would never get to this point by myself. Just as a final note, I have yet another limitation, up until the limit of 4915 row the function works fine (A$2:A$4915). This is also the number of rows that the cell value is a number, the remaining ones are text chars. Thus, if I increase the range (A$2:A$8852) or ideally (A:A), I get a #VALUE! error. Is there any way around this to use this function but deal with chars as well?

Comment: I'd have to think about that one! Can you give me an idea what the text values look like plz?

Comment: And are the text values considered to be 'higher' than the numeric ones?

Comment: And are the text values in any particular order?

Comment: The text values can only be 3: "not ranked" "dropped from top 30" and "new in top 30". Whereas the numbers range from -100 to 100. The text values are not relevant for the large/small function and can be left out for all that matters. They don't have any order as well within the 8852 list.

Comment: OK if you just want to exclude them then it shouldn't be too difficult. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Perfect. Can't thank you enough! And yes, will keep it limited to a number so it doesn't require so much processing. Many thanks again.